# Combine several rows with timestamps into one row with start and end timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull some SQL reports from an inventory system backend.

The table I'm trying to report on has an 'action' column (for tracking check in or out) and a 'timestamp' column.

I'm trying to reformat those into rows for each user/asset combo that has start and end times.

Sample data:

current:

```
row_id** user asset out_or_in timestamp 
1        a    4     out       8:40      
2        c    7     out       9:20      
3        a    4     in        9:55      
4        b    4     out       10:00     
5        c    6     out       12:15     
6        a    3     out       12:30     
7        b    4     in        13:10     
8        a    3     in        14:05     
9        b    4     out       15:00     
10       b    4     in        16:20
```

desired

```
row id** user asset out_time in_time 
1        a    4     8:40     9:55    
2        c    7     9:20             
3        b    4     10:00    13:10   
4        c    6     12:15            
5        a    3     12:30    14:05   
6        b    4     15:00    16:20
```

** not necessary, just included for table correctness

It gets more complicated by the fact that each user-asset pair can be repeated and would need to show as two rows.

Thoughts?

Comment: When  an user-asset pair  is repeated, how out-in events would be paired?

Comment: Ah, forgot the DBMS. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Serg Modified the example to show how b-4 should turn out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql 8.0 using `row_number()` window function to match out/in

```
select usr,asset
  , max(case event when 'out' then ts end) out_time
  , max(case event when 'in' then ts end) in_time
from (
  select f.*,
      -- first 'out' matches first 'in' and so on
      row_number() over(partition by usr, asset, event order by ts) as grp
  from foo f
  ) t
group by usr, asset, grp
order by out_time
```

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b259d317669d2eb8a183876982348c92)

Comment: Both of your queries (you and @lukstorms ) answered for me, thanks. Now to look up all the high-level SQL so I can unpack this query, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query for MySql 8 that makes use of a MIN OVER to calculate the in_time.

```
SELECT q.user, q.asset, q.out_time, q.in_time
FROM
(
    SELECT t.user, t.asset, t.out_or_in, 
     CASE WHEN t.out_or_in = 'out' THEN t.`timestamp` END AS out_time,
     MIN(CASE WHEN t.out_or_in = 'in' THEN t.`timestamp` END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.user, t.asset ORDER BY t.`timestamp` ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS in_time
    FROM YourTable t
) q
WHERE q.out_time IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY q.out_time;
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af5af52e3f439646f5e271b2ed792851)*

Result:

```
user    asset   out_time    in_time
a       4       08:40:00    09:55:00
c       7       09:20:00    
b       4       10:00:00    13:10:00
c       6       12:15:00    
a       4       12:30:00    14:05:00
```

Comment: Both of your queries (you and @serg ) answered for me, thanks. Now to look up all the high-level SQL so I can unpack this query, lol.